# ResponseStatusException - Spring boot - Retorno da mensagem

Tags: java, spring, restful

Sou novo em java e estou criado um  API afim de treinamento e  mim deparei com o seguinte problema:

Faço a requisição via postman, o retorno do JSON esta ok, mas  se faço uma busca que não retorna nada o modelo de mensagem abaixo é retornado:

```
    {
        "timestamp": "2020-06-04T23:52:13.722+00:00",
        "status": 404,
        "error": "Not Found",
        "message": "",
        "path": "/api/produtos/2"
    }
```

Até aqui tudo bem, o que acontece é que a atributo `message` não e preenchido.

Uso o `org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException.ResponseStatusException` do Spring.

```
        @RestController
        @RequestMapping("/api/produtos/")
        public class ProdutoController {
            @Autowired
            ProdutoService produtoService;

            @GetMapping("{id}")
            public Produto getById(@PathVariable Integer id) {
                return produtoService.findById(id)
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Produto não encontrado."));

            }
        }

        @Service
        public class ProdutoService {
           @Autowired
           ProdutoRepository produtoRepository;

           public Optional<Produto> findById(Integer id){
              return produtoRepository.findById(id);
            }
        }
```

Comment: qual versão você está usando do spring boot?

Comment: Eu usei a versão v2.3.0.RELEASE e o problema está lá.

Comment: Veja minha resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por default, sprint boot não mostra essa variável. Você pode verificar os valores default aqui: [Spring Boot Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/).

Para resolver esse problema, basta adicionar no seu `application.yaml`:

```
server:
  error:
    include-message: always
```

ou no seu `application.properties`:

```
server.error.include-message=always
```

Eu acabei de testar o seu código e funcionou corretamente:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-06-05T10:56:36.008+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "Produto não encontrado.",
    "path": "/api/produtos/2"
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Patrick, o problema foi resolvido!

Answer (score 0):

Fiz o teste customizando uma exception mas não funcionou.

Não é a maneira mais elegante mas resolve o seu problema.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("product")
public class ProductController {

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public ResponseEntity getById(@PathVariable Integer id) {

        Optional<Produto> product = new Service().findById(id);

        if(!product.isPresent()) {
            return new ResponseEntity(new Erro("produto nao encontrado"), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity(product, HttpStatus.FOUND);
    }
}

class Produto {
    public long id;
}

class Service{
    public Optional<Produto> findById(Integer id){
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}

class Erro{
    public String message;

    public Erro(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela solução, com o procedimento que Patrick postou consegui resolver!